# How do I run code after intercepting web requests?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, httpwebrequest, raspberry-pi4

I have a raspberry pi that I'm already using to track browsing data and block websites using pihole.

What I'm trying to do is search for a specific web request and when I see the request I want to grab the body data so I can perform some code before continuing with the original request.

I looked into proxies but I don't think that's what I need.

I can make it work on the raspberry pi if it would be easy but I would rather make an extension for chrome that can perform a command. Any example code of this would be great.

Comment: You should take a look at the [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

Comment: lol that's what I'm looking at right now. I think it will work for me. I've decided to use node js on the pi to do all the labor while using the extension to get the info and push to node js